# failed assertion:line 5054 : '_dependents.isEmpty' is not true

Tags: flutter

I'm fluter newbie. I wrote some basic code like below and run symulator but it has error like a picture. [image: symulator error]

I searched with those keywords but couldn't find result related flutter..
How can I work arrange this problem?

Source code below attatched!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 1,
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          actions: [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.person), onPressed: (){},)],
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.note_alt),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.list_alt),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text("You can upload here"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("You can load data here"),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text("Settings Page"),
            ),
          ],
        )

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used the codes following flutter's formal page about TabBar class.

Comment: please add the code that you have done.

Comment: For me everything runs ok, try restarting the app (maybe even the emulator)

Comment: try to upgrade the flutter , `flutter upgrade -f`